# Angular 4 -ngx-toggle-switch not working with ngfor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular4-forms

I have many devices.I want to show each device alert status using ui-switch.suppose all devicedata like

```
 alldevicedata=[{"id": 23,  "alertonoff": "1"},
 {"id": 34,  "alertonoff": "0"},
 {"id": 35,  "alertonoff": "1"},
 {"id": 36,  "alertonoff": "0"} ]
```

Html is like,

```
    <div *ngFor="let item of alldevicedata" class="form-group">
          Alert
          <span class="floatright">             
               <ui-switch  id="alertonoff" name="alertonoff" size="small"
               [(ngModel)]="toggleValue"  (ngModelChange)="item.alertonoff=toggleValue ?'1':'0'" 
                color="#1abc9c"></ui-switch>
           </span>
         </div>
```

if I toogle the switch then that perticular item alertonoff value changes properly.means if I change the 2nd number switch on then 2nd item value changes only.

But at a time all switch changes status. means if toggle the 2nd number switch to on then all other also  turned on like this.

I want to show status of each alert ,if alldevicedata.alertonoff=1,then ui switch turned on otherwise off.
Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zg21jt?embed=1&file=src/app/app.module.ts
     Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you add your code in stackbiz so we can help you miss @priya

Comment: Ok.Give me some time

Comment: Sorry to forgt but what version of angular are you using

Comment: sorry. "ngx-toggle-switch": "^2.0.5",

Comment: i am asking about angular version

Comment: "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",

Comment: priya have add in stackbiz ??? please do it

Comment: "https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zg21jt?embed=1&file=src/app/app.module.ts"  stackblitz url

Comment: I have added my answer right below, go through it & please replace that line, that would solve your requirement. or https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tzq8ky

Answer (score 2):

This happens because all switches are binding to the same value. Try change ngModel like this:

```
<ui-switch  id="alertonoff" name="alertonoff" size="small" [(ngModel)]="item.checked"  (ngModelChange)="onModelChanged(item)" color="#1abc9c"></ui-switch>
```

and in the component class:

```
allDeviceData = [
    { 'id': 23,  'alertonoff': '1', 'checked': true },
    { 'id': 34,  'alertonoff': '0', 'checked': false },
    { 'id': 35,  'alertonoff': '1', 'checked': true },
    { 'id': 36,  'alertonoff': '0', 'checked': false }
];

onModelChanged(item) {
    item.alertonoff = item.checked ? '1' : '0';
    console.log(item.id, item.alertonoff);
}
```

Comment: I've added the property `checked` to not modify the `alertonoff` property. You can do the direct binding on `alertonoff` property, however, all switches will be on at the start because the ui-switch expect **boolean** values and when you toggle some switch the `alertonoff` property are modified to true or false.

Answer (score 1):

your code is correct just you are missing a object property name.
Since you are looping all over items and every item's switch is binded with the same value
so replace this code with yours.

pay attention to this line:  [(ngModel)]="toggleValue"  to ---> **[(ngModel)]="item.alertonoff"**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of alldevicedata" class="form-group">
    Alert
    <span class="floatright">

              <ui-switch  id="alertonoff" name="alertonoff" size="small" [(ngModel)]="item.alertonoff"  (ngModelChange)="item.alertonoff=toggleValue ?'1':'0'" color="#1abc9c"></ui-switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<p>
  Start editing to see some magic happen :)
</p>
<div *ngFor="let item of alldevicedata" class="form-group">
    Alert{{item.alertonoff}}
    <span class="floatright">

              <ui-switch  id="alertonoff" name="alertonoff" size="small"[(ngModel)]="item.alertonoff" color="#1abc9c"></ui-switch>
            </span>
 </div>
```